# Tor with SSH Server on top of it

Tags: ssh, vpn

One of the problems with tor is the exit node - if it's a malicious, it can sniff all the traffic.
If I will chain Tor and SSH server (Tor->SSH Server->Internet), the exit node will be able to decrypt my traffic or it will route it to the SSH server and only the SSH server will be able to see the plaintext traffic?

Comment: The whole point of tor is deniability. The moment you throw a SSH server with a known IP address that's gone.

Comment: What do you mean by strip? From whom do you wish to conceal your identity? The ISP or other listening parties along the way? The destination servers? If the latter, the SSH server will of course be your "exit node" to the rest of the world and not Tor, so you could just as well connect directly to the ssh server.

Comment: @nitro2k01: My question is about the ability to see the data in non - encrypted form, not about anonymity. I want to conceal my traffic from the TOR exit node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the encryption that is used is safe, any man in the middle cannot see the plaintext data. That is the purpose of the encryption, and it works the same over Tor, as any other communication channel. So in general, the answer is yes. Note however that this requires that...

1. The encryption isn't too weak. For example, you should avoid using SSH version 1.
2. The encryption implementation doesn't have bugs. One famous such attack is the [SSL renegotiation attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Renegotiation_attack) that surfaced in 2009. If both your SSH client and server haven't been updated since 2009, you may be vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack based on that vulnerability.
3. That you understand how the SSH security works. SSH needs to connect to obtain an SSL fingerprint from the server in order to trust the server. This is automatically done when you connect for the first time. If this fingerprint is different when you connect another time, which would be the case in a trivial man-in-the-middle attack, you will get a warning. If you ignore this warning, your data isn't safe. If you connect to a particular server for the first time through an untrusted channel, your data isn't safe.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is about the ability to see the data in non - encrypted form, not about anonymity. I want to conceal my traffic from the TOR exit node.

If this is your aim, then you do not need Tor: ssh alone prevents anyone from decrypting it. Just forget about Tor, and the heavy overhead of a further round of encryption and a tortuous route to your final destination.

Tor is meant to hide A's access to resource B, from anyone eavesdropping on either A or B. In other words, it not only hides (=encrypts) the content of the conversation from eavesdroppers, it also conceals the fact that there is an ongoing conversation between A and B.

However, you are **not** concerned with hiding the fact that you are contacting your ssh server, only with making the content of the conversation unintelligible to the eavesdroppers. For that, openssh is more than enough.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Vulnerabilities)  states:

> **Vulnerabilities**
>
> In November 2008, a theoretical vulnerability was discovered for all versions of SSH which allowed recovery of up to 32 bits of plaintext from a block of ciphertext that was encrypted using what was then the standard default encryption mode, CBC.The most straightforward solution is to use CTR mode instead of CBC mode, since this renders SSH resistant to the attack.
>
> **OpenSSH**
>
> In the case of using the standard OpenSSH configuration, the attacker's success probability for recovering 32 bits of plaintext is 2^{-18}.The OpenSSH 5.2 release modified the behavior of the OpenSSH server to further mitigate against this vulnerability.

It seems to me that these odds should inspire confidence, except perhaps when the NSA is the eavesdropper. But then, I am not interesting to them.